# Structure question

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Would you elaborate on the following sentence structure and grammar. It seems somewhat complex. What is the function of "becoming prosperous" in the sentence? Is it a reduced form (if yes, for what?)? In the case that it shows contrast, why has the author used *and* as a conjunction?

> They succeeded, becoming prosperous, and piety mingled with smugness made the whole family insufferably sententious.

The context of this sentence is a paragraph from [Paul Theroux's article](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/ist/?next=/arts-culture/The-Trouble-With-Autobiography.html?c=y&page=6) in the *Smithsonian* magazine, "The Trouble with Autobiography":

> My maternal grandparents, Alessandro and Angelina Dittami, were relative newcomers to America, having emigrated separately from Italy around 1900. An Italian might recognize Dittami (“Tell me”) as an orphan’s name. Though he abominated any mention of it, my grandfather was a foundling in Ferrara. As a young man, he got to know who his parents were—a well-known senator and his housemaid. After a turbulent upbringing in foster homes, and an operatic incident (he threatened to kill the senator), Alessandro fled to America and met and married my grandmother in New York City. They moved to Medford with the immigrant urgency and competitiveness to make a life at any cost. They succeeded, becoming prosperous, and piety mingled with smugness made the whole family insufferably sententious.

Comment: "Becoming prosperous" means that "they" got rich. The "and" has the sense of "and so" or "and then". It's just telling you the consequence of "their" success.

Comment: What is the full structure of the reduced structure "becoming prosperous"?

Comment: What makes you think there's any "contrast" involved? We don't have full context, but presumably the family have already been identified as "pious". The text as given strongly implies their success resulted in prosperity, and pragmatically we can assume that prosperity led to smugness. We're looking at *consequences,* not contrasts. I've no idea how to describe "becoming prosperous" in syntactic terms, nor do I even know if it would the the same with, say, "being determined".

Comment: @Mani You might consider the fuller structure to be "they became prosperous". Without the word "they" in that phrase, the continuous tense avoids the impression that the prosperity came after the success.

Comment: @Lawrence: Sounds good to me. But note that if we apply the same principles to my "being determined", we more or less *have* to include a conjunction to explicitly state the relationship between the main and the "parenthetical" clause: *They succeeded **because** they **were** determined, and...*.

Comment: Within the context of the whole sentence, 'becoming prosperous' is a parenthetical, restating/developing the initial independent clause. One could rephrase: 'They succeeded – they became prosperous – and piety ... // 'becoming prosperous' itself is a participial phrase/clause in this example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's true. The difference is that *prosperous* is a restatement of *succeeded* as Edwin Ashworth notes, while *determined* isn't.

Comment: @Lawrence: Exactly. Which leads me to think the fact that the *actual* parenthetical clause here can be reasonably described as a "restatement" doesn't really help us in *structural* terms (since it's not obvious to me that "being determined" is actually a "different structure"). I think it's more generic to say that in both cases there's a pragmatically implicit relationship between the parenthetical and the main clause: ***leading to their** becoming prosperous*, and ***because of their** being determined* for those two specific examples.

Comment: ...but they are both "consequential" relationships (one in one direction, the other in the other). Are there other structurally similar parenthetical clauses based on relationships other than consequence?

Comment: My question concerned syntactic structure of the whole sentence and specifically "becoming prosperous"!

Comment: @Mani: Well, Edwin's obviously quite right that 'becoming prosperous' is a parenthetical (since it can be removed completely - it just "expands on" the preceding clause). After which the actual word ***and*** simply allows the writer to continue with what would otherwise just be another sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I found this link about [explanatory phrases](http://classroom.synonym.com/difference-between-appositive-explanatory-phrase-4811.html) - they are structurally similar to appositives (each is a phrase separated from the rest of the sentence by commas) but they add information to the sentence instead of acting on just their head noun. (I don't think *being determined* or *becoming prosperous* are appositives.) It seems to work with both, structurally. Sound about right?

Comment: ... I also read a little about [transformational grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformational_grammar). It looks intriguing and relates to my clumsy attempt at answering Mani's follow-up question to me, but I think that might be reaching for sledgehammers where this question is concerned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but with your quoted sentence making perfect sense, I'm not sure what exactly your question is:

'they succeeded,' -> well, they became successful at something

'becoming prosperous,' -> they 'prospered', ie. their business grew, they became rich, etc.

'piety mingled with smugness' -> ok, as a native Dutch speaker, this one is a bit trickier, though mostly because 'piety' describes a concept rather than have one clear meaning (imo) and can apply to religion, spirituality and family, but what it says here is (assuming the phrase refers to filial piety) 'their sense of duty toward each other mixed with self confidence'

'insufferably sententious' -> 'sententious' can have different specific meanings, so any accurate rephrasing would require more context. However, I guess it can be read as 'meddlesome to an extreme'.

'They became successful, made a lot of money, and their sense of duty to their family combined with their self confidence turned them into a very annoying meddlesome lot' (I guess it's a very fancy way of saying 'they got money, and now they're acting like they're too big for their boots').

OK, this is rather rough rephrasing, but I hope it helps understanding the sentence and how its wording is not showing contrast.
The usage of 'and' simply appears to indicate that the 'insufferably sententiousness' is the result of them succeeding and becoming prosperous.

Comment: I don't think OP has any problems *understanding* the cited text. He's asking for a structural breakdown / analysis, not a paraphrasing to "clarify" the meaning.

Comment: Exactly, I wish to understand structural analysis of the whole sentence.